# Bigquery API limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-run

I'm writing a Google Cloud Run service containing a python code to stream data to bigquery. I'm sending between 100k-1M request per second but I often see this error

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET
> https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/  prettyPrint=false: Exceeded
> rate limits

Also I see that the cloud run instance can only have 300 request/s.
[image]

I don't understand where is the bottleneck

- On cloud run, I have a concurrency of 1000 per container
- The auto scaling of max 100 container has not been reached
- The python code use the google-cloud-bigquery library and the TableData.insertAll() method quota is 10,000 requests per second per table (https://developers.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#streaminginserts) and I'm far from that !

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're doing something like getting the table stats (e.g. fetching schema frequently)?  The error implies you're **not** just calling the streaming insert method, as that's an HTTP `POST` and the error appears to be attributed to a `GET` request.

Comment: Yes the code verify if the table exist before insert and check the number of cols.
How many ´GET´ request can we have? Is there any way to increase the quota?

Comment: As shollyman said it must be related to a GET request, or maybe to a global one. You could check your [quota](console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) to see which one is getting the limit, and ask for an increment for some of them. Anyway, why are you making so many GETs, it couldn’t be done in a different way? Also in the case that you also want to avoid the "insert" limit I would like to suggest using [batch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data) which only will let inserts when there are resources for them.